# How can I move the last element of an array to the front upon 200 response using hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, react-hooks

The `useEffect()` is responsible for displaying all data (it gets an array).  When the user navigates to the page, all photos will be displayed automatically.

Once the user uploads successfully and you refresh the page, the uploaded photo correctly appears on the bottom along with the other already uploaded photos above it.

However, I'd like the newly uploaded photo to appear at the top instead of the bottom upon the user uploading data.

In other words, move it to element to the front of the array so that when the user refreshes, the data appears on top and not on the bottom.

I know `unshift()` should be used to achieve this but I've tried many ways in the `fileUpload()` function but to no avail. How can I achieve this?  Should this even be handled on the client side or server?

```
useEffect(() => {
    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    };

    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-user-uploads-data', {headers})
        .then(resp => {
            setGridData(resp.data);
        }).catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });

}, []);


const fileUpload = () => {
    const url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/file-upload';

    let formData = new FormData();
    let imagefile = document.querySelector('#file');
    formData.append("image", imagefile.files[0]);

    const headers = {
        "Accept": 'application/json',
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${authToken}`
    }

    axios.post(url, formData, {headers})
        .then(resp => {

            let first = localStorage.getItem('UserID') === gridData[0]['UserID'];
            gridData.unshift(first);

        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: you should either sort your display array based on the upload date-time or make sure your backend will give back the array based on the upload date-time

Comment: I would recommend sorting your photos in the backend but if you want a quick solution just use setGridData(resp.data.reverse()). It will reverse the response array so last element will be at the top.

Answer (score 0):

If you're refreshing the page, your component is reloading and your API call inside useEffect is getting the fresh copy of the data from the server side again.
If you really want your data to be displayed in the latest upload first order, you could sort them with timestamps(if you have that information available) or get this data sorted already from the server side.

*Keep in mind that if you have a long list and plan to paginate it, it's better to do it on the server side otherwise on each fetch the sorting on the frontend side will not look very good because of some other items shifting randomly.*